# Simulate end of drag in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uicontrol

When a user scrolls a certain distance horizontally beyond the contentSize of my scrollView I want to 'take over' and run some animations.  The problem is that even if I turn off user interaction as soon as this happens, the 'drag' operation is still ongoing.  Only when the user releases his touch is interaction disabled.

Is there a way to programmatically simulate the touch up at the end of the drag? The end result should be that when my trigger fires, the user is immediately unable to manipulate the view any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could temporarily set the scrollView's `scrollEnabled` property to `NO`.  (Unlike the `userInteractionEnabled` property, toggling `scrollEnabled` has immediate effect.)  You can turn it back on again when your animation is done.

### From Apple's documentation:

#### scrollEnabled

A Boolean value that determines whether scrolling is enabled.

`@property(nonatomic, getter=isScrollEnabled) BOOL scrollEnabled`

#### Discussion

If the value of this property is YES, scrolling is enabled, and if it is NO, scrolling is disabled. The default is YES.

When scrolling is disabled, the scroll view does not accept touch events; it forwards them up the responder chain.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use gesture recognizer to detect the user's touch.That should solve your problem.But still to be more clear can you post the code fragment where you have tried to detect the touch?

Comment: I'm not doing anything special - the scroll view is handling the touch events. I just need a way to tell it to stop responding.

Comment: Don't use the delegate methods of scrollview.Use scrollView.delegate=nil. That should help you.